# Is your issue tracker behind the firewall?

Tags: issue-tracking

I'm thinking of making a web service that can file bugs on issue trackers through (mainly) xml-rpc. But I'd like to get a sense whether issue trackers nowadays tend to be available behind the firewall or on the internet...

The target for this web service would be companies that build websites.

So is your issue tracker (jira, bugzilla, trac etc) behind the firewall? (as opposed to being accessible on the internet)

Thanks!

Comment: A local server with VPN combines all the advantages.

Comment: As opposed to being accessible via the internet without a firewall?

Comment: thanks OMG -- have improved the text in my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At our shop, our bug tracker is accessible, because certain clients are allowed to file bugs. It really makes things easier, because the developer working on the ticket can directly solicit feedback from the client, rather than trying to get the project manager to get in touch and ask the right questions.

We had thought about doing something similar to what it sounds like you're thinking of, but never got around to implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ours is.  We have it there partly for security and partly because there was no need to have it public to the world.

Answer (score 1):

An issue tracker behind the firewall?! So it means you won't allow users outside to submit issues, and this is actually the only difference.
They could mail issues / bugs to someone inside, then ask the recipient to create that issue / bug.
BTW, the issue tracker of our company is behind the firewall, we really need to control every detail, as the users may not know what the problem is. We use firewall to ensure higher security and easier management.